# Match certain string on second line of text with regex

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I'm new to regex, and would appreciate some guidance/help.

Currently, I'm looking to write an expression, that derives a certain part of text from the 2nd line of the provided text.

Here is the text:

123 anywhere Avenue
Winnipeg, Manitoba R3E 0L7
Canada
Pharmacy Manager: person person
Pharmacy Licence Holder/Owner: 123456 Manitoba Ltd.

see correct formatting with code [here](https://regexr.com/53e51)

My goal is to derive the 'Manitoba' string  from the second line, however I'd like to make it dynamic rather than writing an expression to always fetch Manitoba as a static. I used the below code to target the second line:

`(.*)(?=(\n.*){3}$)`

(It matches 3 lines up from the last line, thus targeting the desired line)

I noticed, that within the dataset, that the Province (Manitoba) is always in between two spaces.

Is there any addition I can make to the code, so that the expression only targets the second line, then matches the first string in-between spaces?

Perhaps using a lazy expression with a positive lookaround?

If I target all matches in between spaces, it would take both 'Manitoba' and 'R3E 0L7' which I dont want.

I want it to only match the first piece of text in between spaces on the second line.

Any help is much appreciated :-)

Thanks.

Comment: Try `^.*\r?\n\S+[^\S\r\n]+(\S+).*(?=(?:\n.*){3}$)`  https://regex101.com/r/Aiy2kl/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Would you be so kind as to provide an explanation regarding how i works? That would be much appreciated. Looks like it does indeed work.

Comment: I have added it as an answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to match the first line, then capture the second word in the second lines in capturing **group 1**.

Then match the rest of the second line and assert what follows is 3 times a line.

```
^.*\r?\n\S+[^\S\r\n]+(\S+).*(?=(?:\r?\n.*){3}$)
```

In parts:

- `^` Start of string
- `.*\r?\n` Match the whole lines and a newline
- `\S+` Match 1+ non whitespace char (the first "word")
- `[^\S\r\n]+` Match 1+ times a whitespace char except newlines
- `(\S+)` Capture **group 1** Match 1+ times a non whitespace char (the second "word')
- `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what follows on the right is

  - `(?:\r?\n.*){3}$` Match 3 times a newline followed by 0+ times any except a newline and assert the end of the string
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/F0LSbZ/1)

You could also turn the lookahead in to a match instead

```
^.*\r?\n\S+[^\S\r\n]+(\S+).*(?:\r?\n.*){3}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tjtl9u/1)